# GetXmlHttpObject AJAX call to a php file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call a php file using GetXmlHttpObject object and having some luck, but seem to have problem with the URL variable.

Is there something I have to do with the URL string differently?

Here is the relevant code:

```
remoteCounter('marks');//invoking function

document.write("<div id=\"marks\"></div>");//destination div

function GetXmlHttpObject () {

 var xmlHttp = null;

 try {
   // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari, IE 7+
   xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e) {
   // Internet Explorer - old IE - prior to version 7
   try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e) {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 }

 return xmlHttp;
}


function remoteCounter(param){
counterObj = GetXmlHttpObject();

var url="HTTP://dnsname/directory/view.php?" + param;
alert(url + " " + counterObj);

counterObj.open("GET", url , true);
counterObj.onreadystatechange=updateCounter;
counterObj.send(null);
}

function updateCounter(){
//alert('updateCounter');
    if (counterObj.readyState == 4 || counterObj.readyState == "complete"){
        document.getElementById("marks").innerHTML=counterObj.responseText;
    }
}
```

I can replace the counterObj.responseText variable in document.getElementById("marks").innerHTML=counterObj.responseText;

and see the test string correctly in the source document, so I know the html and jscript source is not the problem.

I have commented out code in the view.php file to just echo a simple string, but that is not showing either - which again makes me think the problem is in the request to the file, not in the file, not in the source.

Actual server name and directory have been replaced by dnsname/directory for this post. Including alert for debugging.

thank you for assistance.

Comment: This won't solve the above, but I strongly advice you to have a look on jQuery for this sort of things.

Comment: Does that last `alert('updateCounter');` ever fire?

Comment: Install firebug firefox extension to debug this. It is very easy to use and it will make debugging your problem easier. Monitor the ajax request and response using firebug Net panel. You will see what is the response with header details and request data.

Comment: @Krister - I have used jquery, but did not feel this simplified the task much.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc - yes, it fires.

Comment: @Manjula - thanks, good idea - i will do this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace order of two first lines:

```
document.write("<div id=\"marks\"></div>"); //destination div

remoteCounter('marks');  //invoking function
```

It's necesary declarate div tag with id *"marks"* first.